# How to configure httpj:connector with Jetty9

Tags: spring, cxf, jetty-9

I have a spring project where I am currently using Jetty 8, here is my config for `httpj:engine`

```
<httpj:engine port="${service.port}">
  <!-- <httpj:tlsServerParametersRef id="secure" /> -->
  <httpj:threadingParameters minThreads="2" maxThreads="20" />
  <httpj:connector>
    <bean class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector">
       <property name="port" value="${service.port}" />
    </bean>
  </httpj:connector>
  <httpj:handlers>
    <bean class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.DefaultHandler"/>
  </httpj:handlers>
</httpj:engine>
```

Jetty 9, however does not have any blocking connectors. How can I make my configuration work with Jetty 9